# Query to get top product gainers by sales over previous week

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, top-n

I have a database table with three columns.

`WeekNumber`, `ProductName`, `SalesCount`

Sample data is shown in below table. I want top 10 gainers(by %) for week 26 over previous week i.e. week 25. The only condition is that the product should have sales count greater than 0 in both the weeks.

In the sample data B,C,D are the common products and C has the highest % gain.

Similarly, I will need top 10 losers also.

What I have tried till now is to make a inner join and get common products between two weeks. However, I am not able to get the top gainers logic.

[image]

The output should be like

```
 Product    PercentGain

  C            400%

  D            12.5%

  B            10%
```

Comment: Give us the table structure & what you have tried till now

Comment: Can you provide a sample required output (use a small number, 2, instead of 10)

Comment: please post the sample output

Comment: @Amit, I have updated the question details.

Comment: Are you looking for results specific to a certain week number, or top/bottom 10 per week?

Comment: @Amit, this is part of a dashboard. Every week the data will be updated and data for current week vs previous week shall be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you a generic answer, not just for any particular week:

```
select top 10 product , gain [gain%]
from 
(
SELECT product, ((curr.salescount-prev.salescount)/prev.salescount)*100 gain 
from   
  (select weeknumber, product, salescount from tbl) prev
  JOIN
  (select weeknumber, product, salescount from tbl) curr
on prev.weeknumber = curr.weeknumber - 1
AND prev.product = curr.product
where prev.salescount > 0 and curr.salescount > 0
)A 
order by gain desc
```

If you are interested in weeks 25 and 26, then just add the condition below in the `WHERE` clause:

```
and prev.weeknumber = 25
```

Comment: Everything about this query is right except the formula. Instead of (curr.salescount-prev.salescount)/curr.salescount, I am using ( (curr.Sales - prev.Sales ) *100)/prev.Sales. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL-Server 2012 (or newer), you could use the [`lag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function to match "this" weeks sales with the previous week's. From there on, it's just some math:

```
SELECT   TOP 10 product, sales/prev_sales - 1 AS gain
FROM     (SELECT product, 
                 sales, 
                 LAG(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY product 
                                  ORDER BY weeknumber) AS prev_sales
          FROM   mytable) t
WHERE    weeknumber = 26 AND
         sales > 0 AND
         prev_sales > 0 AND
         sales > prev_sales
ORDER BY sales/prev_sales
```

Comment: OP doesn't say whether it is SQL Server 2012+. You should explicitly mention this clause.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti Since SQL-Server 2012 is already several years old, I just assumed OP wouldn't be using anything older. But you are correct, this needs to be stated. I've edited my answer with this clarification.

Answer (score 1):

this is the Query .

```
select top 10 product , gain [gain%]
from 
(
SELECT curr.Product, ( (curr.Sales - prev.Sales ) *100)/prev.Sales gain 
from   
  (select weeknumber, product, sales from ProductInfo where weeknumber = 25 ) prev
  JOIN
  (select weeknumber, product, sales from ProductInfo where weeknumber = 26 ) curr
on    prev.product = curr.product
where prev.Sales > 0 and curr.Sales > 0
)A 
order by gain desc
```

Comment: I am sorry `SQL fiddle`  is not working right now  there is some error.